# Black screen trying to use Unity desktop on a Samsung Chrombook

Tags: unity, samsung, chromebook

I cannot open the unity desktop on my Samsung Chromebook. When I toggle to it I get a completely black screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should have ran:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n chrootname
```

(unity, kde, or which ever version your running)

Make sure you try that next time before just starting over.